# How to sort mixed strings in Excel?

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula

I wish to sort the following mixed strings in Excel:

```
A987G
D301N
A809V
N408K
```

so they run:

```
D301N
N408K
A809V
A987G
```

They're always in the format letter-number-letter(s). I wish them to be sorted smallest to largest. Can someone please tell me how to do this? [I don't have a Linux environment running on my work PC so can't solve it that way!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=--MID(A1,2,3)
```

and copy down.  Then sort cols **A** and **B** by **B**

[image]

Comment: Oh that's so easy! Thank you!

Comment: IMPORTANT... the last 2 in this formula MUST be a 3 instead!

Comment: @ExcelHero  Thank you for the correction.  I will fix my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way may be, to a copy of the column containing your data, to apply Text to Columns Fixed width splitting on second and fifth characters. Then sort on those three columns:

[image: SO33214373 example]

Comment: Thank you for this - annoyingly I had previously concatenated about a third of this data *out* of this format to match the rest of the dataset, but next time I think I will split everything to match this. Cheers!

Comment: @CharleyFarley The key in doing data manipulation like this is to first understand (1) how you can get your data to look in your initial data dump; and (2) how you need it to look to get your final Excel results. Wherever you have the ability to manipulate your data pre-Excel (ie: by configuring how the dump flows from your database system), it is quite likely that that will be a better solution than doing all the manipulation in Excel.

Comment: @pnuts I agree fully; I've worked with some terrible database systems in the past, and the knee-jerk response to a problem is often to attempt an Excel solution, but long-term the better idea is usually to get an understanding of the database so that your data comes out as clean and uniform as possible.

Comment: In this case, I have copied and pasted data from 50 different scientific papers to create my database. I'me therefore hamstrung by the original format of the table, whether I can download it as a CSV or must rip the text wholesale into Excel. Each dataset therefore needs a separate fix. Until there is a standardised way to present the data I'm interested in (amino acid changes) and the phenotypes associated with them, I have no control over how I get the data :(